# Macro to change PowerPoint Presentation slides with random background colors

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint, colors, presentations, background

Is there a macro that can change the PowerPoint slides to have random background colors? I have looked for the PowerPoint themes, but usually they have few colors scheme.

I am looking for a way to automatically apply random background colors to existing PowerPoint slides?

#### Here is an example:

[image]

#### Nice to Have:

- It would be nice to have a control over sequence of colors to pick from.

#### Note:

- I can manually change individual background colors. But that is not the intent of this question.
- 

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below. It loops through the slides and changes their background colors. The colors are selected randomly for each slide.

Note: When testing, I noticed that I had to change the slides' background color from white to another color for a slide to start changing its color. I advise you do the same.

```
Sub SetRandomBackground()

    Dim x, red, blue, green As Integer
    Dim myslide As Slide

    For Each myslide In ActivePresentation.Slides
       
            red = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
            blue = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
            green = Int((255 * Rnd) + 1)
            myslide.Background.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(red, green, blue)

    Next

End Sub
```

[image: IMG:]